# Trying to hide an object in an array when it is clicked, works without an array but not with? Actionscript 3.0

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I am making a little game and I have an array. The array contains 4 characters. When one of the characters is clicked the opacity should turn to 0, if another is clicked the same should also happen.

So far I have put the array into a function but the function will only hide one of the characters, and not even the one which is clicked. Could anyone help me please? Here is the code I have:

```
for(var g:int = 0; g<ghostsL.length; g++){
ghostsL[g].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickGrey)
};
function clickGrey(e:MouseEvent):void{
        this.ghostsL[i].alpha = 0;
        var npoint:NPoint = new NPoint();
        npoint.play();
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not know what `this.ghostsL[i]` is.

Why don't you just do it this way:

```
function clickGrey(e:MouseEvent):void{
        MovieClip(e.currentTarget).alpha = 0;
        var npoint:NPoint = new NPoint();
        npoint.play();
};
```

Comment: Awesome that works perfectly thank you!
Also sorry this was what ghostsL. 
var ghostL1:Ghost_mc = new Ghost_mc();
var ghostL2:Ghost_mc = new Ghost_mc();
var ghostL3:Ghost_mc = new Ghost_mc();
var ghostL4:Ghost_mc = new Ghost_mc();
var ghostsL:Array = [ghostL1,ghostL2,ghostL3,ghostL4];

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider marking this questions as solved. (check mark next to the answer).